# Not able to start/stop tomcat using Capitomcat jenkins plugin on Centos7

Tags: environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, centos7

I am using Capitomcat jenkins plugin to install my war file on remote server after build.
Capitomcat jenkins plugin executing below command but tomcat is not stopping.

**/usr/bin/env sudo -u tomcat8  /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh stop**

When I below run same command on linux server I gets JAVA_HOME is not setup even though it is setup up.

```
tomcat8@qw1189-45 bin]$ /usr/bin/env sudo -u tomcat8  /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh stop
```

> Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
>   At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this
>   program

When in run command - **env** , I see JAVA_HOME is there.

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=260
HOSTNAME=myqanode
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
OLDPWD=/opt
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
USER=tomcat8
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/tomcat8
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/tomcat8/.local/bin:/home/tomcat8/bin:/home/tomcat8/.local/bin:/home/tomcat8/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66
PWD=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_66
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/tomcat8
LOGNAME=tomcat8
LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I see if I run only **/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh stop**  form my linux box it works.

Comment: Instead of running the mentioned plugin, you could just invoke a shell script directly as a `Build step` or whatever, which basically runs this `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh stop`? Or you want to explicitly use this plugin to stop your server?

Comment: I am also thinking same instead of using plugin. let me give a try. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting exception while executing command from jenkins execute shell.                                                                                                             ssh -T root@X.Y.X.S
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/startup.sh                                                 touch: cannot touch ‘/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/catalina.out’: Permission denied
/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/bin/catalina.sh: line 401: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/logs/catalina.out: Permission denied

Comment: you might have to run the script as a super user.